# perl arrays in postgresql insert statement

Tags: arrays, perl, postgresql, mongodb, if-statement

I think i have a logical problem in my code. I have a mongodb with template,value,row,column. For example $record->{template} it's T1 and $record->{column} 1 and $record->{row} i have some dates ("d.m.Y"). I need to arrage @insert_data values depending $record->{row} and $record->{column}

The problem is that i can't use @insert_data[1] or @insert_data[2] or ..etc in that insert statement, but i don't understand why, and i don't understand how can i resolve my problem.

```
while (my $record = $collection->next){
    if($record->{template} eq "T1"){
        my @insert_data;
        if($record->{column} == 1 and $record->{row} != 0){
            #my @insert_data[1] = $record->{VALUE};
        }
        if($record->{column} == 2 and $record->{row} != 0){
            #my @insert_data[2] = $record->{VALUE};
        }
        if($record->{column} == 3 and $record->{row} != 0){
            #my @insert_data[3] = $record->{VALUE};
        }
        if($record->{column} == 4 and $record->{row} != 0){
            #my @insert_data[4] = $record->{VALUE};
        }
        if($record->{column} == 5 and $record->{row} != 0){
            #my @insert_data[5] = $record->{VALUE};
        }
        if($record->{column} == 6 and $record->{row} != 0){
            #my @insert_data[6] = $record->{VALUE};
        }
        $stmt->execute(@insert_data[1],@insert_data[2],@insert_data[3],@insert_data[4],@insert_data[5],@insert_data[6],$record->{template});
    } elsif($record->{template} eq "T5"){

    } elsif($record->{template} eq "T10"){

    }   
}
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty much doing it wrong if you pass successive slots of an array to a method. You should never need to pass `func( $a[1], $a[2], ... $a[n], ...` to a sub. Passing them separately *will* ensure that an argument slot is used so that you might not encounter `$record->{template}` earlier than you expect it, but so will *slice notation*. ( `@a[1..6]` ).

And unless you're doing Perl 6 (you're not) the slots of an array are *scalars*, so you will need the scalar sigil (`$`) to assign to a slot.

As in: `$insert_data[1]`.

Also, anywhere outside of legacy COBOL, this code is horrible: In any modern language, you should not have to branch to access structures. You should just be able to do

```
my $col = $record->{column}; # cache frequently referenced item.
if ( $record->{row} != 0 and $col > 0 and $col < 7 ) {
    $insert_data[ $col ] = $record->{VALUE};
}
```

And why you would want to pass a bunch of undefined values and only one actual value to a query is beyond me, but it looks like this:

```
$stmt->execute( @insert_data[1..6], $record->{template} );
```

Keep in mind that the *slice* notation ( `@a[$i..$j]` ) means that it will send 6 positional values as arguments. This may be important because in both your implementation and my implementation if `$record->{column}` is 1, the array is simply `[ undef, $record->{VALUE} ]`; it simply has 2 elements in it, at offset #0 and offset #1.

Without the slice notation, you pass *two* arguments before `$record->{template}`--probably unexpected. But the slice notation ensures that how ever many slots of the array have actually been assigned and allocated, the resulting expression will take up 6 positions (5 of which will be `undef`).

But first and foremost, for such a newbie as yourself, USUW:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

That needs to go at the top of your code. If you don't understand an error that strict kills the script for you can easily look it up in `perlfaq` and googling a solution is easy as well.

If you don't understand a message that `warnings` is giving, then you can also insert this library at the top of your code:

```
use diagnostics -verbose;
```

Which can tend to give you more explanation than you want to read.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand what was wrong and other explanations. I have one more question if you can help me...  I forgot to mention that all data are corelated. I need to insert all data on the same row. For example: $record->{row} = 1 and $record->{column} [1..6] = one record in my postgresql database. Now, are on 6 records in postgresql.

Answer (score 1):

It would be great to add checks after `$stmt->execute`, ie.

```
 $stmt->execute(@insert_data[1..6], $record->{template}) or die $stmt->errstr;
```

`use strict;` can also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I notice you're not giving us any error messages, but I'll presume this info may be useful:

`@array_name[integer]` is a single element array slice.
`$array_name[integer]` is a scalar value from within the array.

I'd recommend you pass values into the `execute` statement instead of arrays.